# IntelliSense throws #include errors when working with Arduino in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, include, intellisense

I want to develop Arduino code in VS Code. Therefore, I installed the Arduino IDE and the Arduino extension vor VS Code.

Upon opening an Arduino project in VS Code the extension created the following `c_cpp_properties.json` file for IntelliSense (excerpt):

```
"includePath": [
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools/**",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/**"
],
"forcedInclude": [
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
],
```

The forced include `Arduino.h` has the following relative include:

```
// Some includes
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
// Even more includes
```

The problem is that, although `pgmspace.h` does exist it is not located in the path relative to `Arduino.h` (it is not located in one of the two include paths either). Adding the path of `pgmspace.h` to the include paths does not help as IntelliSense seems to be looking for the given relative path.

My question is if there is any possibility to tell IntelliSense via the `c_cpp_properties.json` file to ignore relative paths and just look for the file? Or if you can think of another way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I found an answer myself. If you have the same problem, try the following:

Add to `settings.json`:

```
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"
```

This is a downside as "Tag Parser" is not context-aware.

Add to `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
"configurations": [
  {

    ...,

    "browse": {
      "path": [
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include"
      ],
      "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: In a Windows machine, I just changed "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine" to "Tag Parser" as mentioned above and it worked fine. Also, my "compilerPath" was no properly escaped in c_cpp_properties.json. Windows users just remember to check that out too.

Answer (score 3):

`Arduino.h` is located in `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h` and it has the following snippet:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
```

E.g. the first file `pgmspace.h` is in `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/pgmspace.h` (which you can find for example with the shell command "find / -name pgmspace.h"), and that path cannot be found as <avr/pgmspace.h> relative to where Arduino.h is, of course.

But it can be found relative to `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include`. Add that to your `c_cpp_properties.json`, and VSCode should be able to find the header files.

```
"includePath": [
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools/**",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/**",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include"
],
"forcedInclude": [
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, modify your `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file with the following:

```
"includePath": [
   ...,
   "/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/Arduino/libraries/**"
]
```